# send 1 array with 1 million integers with WCF Web Service equal big timeout?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I created a webService which is related to my application c #.

**All methods works perfectly**. However, a function has problems "**TimeOut**".
This method should return me an array of integers with approximately [1,000,000] **(1 million) of integers.**
I get the data correctly but about **4-5 minutes** after calling my method!
Is it normal to wait about 5 minutes for a table 1millions of integers?
I find it can take too long and annoying for my application.
Do you know a solution or a better way to send large data?

- Other compression method?
- Other response format (xml, array ..)?

---

Here is my configuration file on the server side:

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Elevation_ServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:02:00" messageEncoding="Mtom"
          openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00"
          allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" allowCookies="true"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IImageryService" allowCookies="true"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://gisdata.usgs.gov/XMLWebServices2/Elevation_Service.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Elevation_ServiceSoap"
        contract="ElevationService.Elevation_ServiceSoap" name="Elevation_ServiceSoap" />
      <endpoint address="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/GeocodeService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService"
        contract="GeocodeService.IGeocodeService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService" />
      <endpoint address="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/imageryservice/imageryservice.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IImageryService"
        contract="ImageryService.IImageryService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IImageryService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment - binaryHttp -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Here is my configuration file on the client side:

**App.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:02:00"
                    openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00"
                    allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors >
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="debug">
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://blalbloslblalbla/WebServiceArcadia_World_deploy/Service1.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="WebServiceArcadia_World.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
        <services>
            <service name="WebServiceArcadia_World_deploy.IService1">

            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="1048576" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You may want to give the netTcp binding try, I expect it would be quicker, no idea how much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon.
Finally, the right solution was to change the encoding mode!
Indeed default [WCF] sends the response format "xml" full text. This is enormously heavy!
Devised an array of integers. For each index / value [WCF] tags will add unnecessary text in formats:
Examples.

**XML**

```
<!-- Too heavy with text / tag useless for the customer -->
<xmlns blabalala .........  />
<item>11</item>
<item>2</item>
<item>41</item>
.....
```

**Simple Binary Format / or Json** much lighter etc ...:

```
11,2,41,2,6,7,34,8,43,12,76, .....
```

Anyway I finally changed the method to transmit binary! A page that helped me a lot on the choice of the encoding method and sends streaming or other!

Article by microsoft here -> [Large Data and Streaming - WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

varies from time to time !
~3min - ~3min 30sec - ~4min ... 
But it is already a little better . I think unfortunately there is no other way to do it faster with [WCF] otherwise use a "WebSocket" would be the best solution.
For my application I was hanging use [wcf] ..
I think my methods add webService access mode "async" to allow to add a progressBar during my time downloading.
Other ideas are welcome;-)

Comment: How much does it take now to retrieve the array?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to paginate the result in order to bring less data on each request.

Comment: This request should be called only one time to create the data.
What do you mean by "to paginate the result"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the restriction of only one request. Anyway, the only way I see to optimize it is to do more than one request, returning small portions of data.

Comment: About the other answer, from @Schglurps, you can also do the paging server side, don't you?

Comment: Yes. But the idea is to reduce the download time of my function. And not cut my task several times.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to paginate your results : set a limit (for example 2000) of integers which can be returned by your WCF service, and call it until the response contains 0 number.

Comment: ahh. Ok I understand. But with this solution, it  reduced not  the time it takes to get my entire array? I will repeat several times the call to wait for the same time before? Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're right. If you must call your service only one time, you will have to adjust the WCF timeouts, and probably the maximum size of the responses. You can try to activate gzip compression on server side. Or maybe you'll want to stream your results, in order to process them as soon as they're received.

Comment: I do not know "gzip". Is this a library developped specifically for the zip response in xml format?

Answer (score 1):

If your service and client runs on same pc, try net.pipe binding, if not - try net.tcp binding.